# Creating a multi-index (3 axis) to take the mean of 1 axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrames that consists of a timeseries with a datetime index. I have another list called longname that I want to associate to each of those Dataframes. I would like to group these Dataframes-longname with a list of Mainlabel (which is related through the longname by , MainName,SubName). Now i want to take the mean relative to the datetime index from the dataframe, through the longname And MainNames. I'm sorry if this sounds confusing.

What i have in mind is confusing and complicated. So I was wondering if anyone has a better approach that i should be taking.
What i have done so far is expanding the list of dataframes into 1 column using pd.concat(), but cant seem to label them using the "keys" argument for the longname, giving me an error, 
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (823748, 2), indices imply (3343070, 2)`. 
this looses my 2nd indexer. Which if it worked i was hoping to just easily group them using the shortname .eg.

```
ShortNames = ['MainName1','MainName2']

idx = allvars.index.str.extract('('+ '|'.join(ShortNames) + ')', expand=False)

Allmean = allvars.groupby(idx).mean(axis = (1,2,3))
```

I have multiple dataframes that look likes this one;

```
            Amount(mm)
Date                  
1900-01-01         0.0
1900-01-02         0.0
1900-01-03         5.1
1900-01-04         0.0
1900-01-05         0.0
1900-01-06         0.0
1900-01-07         0.0
```

the list of longnames i have is like:

```
longnames = ['MainName1,SubName1', 'MainName1,SubName2', 'MainName2,SubName1', 'MainName2,SubName2']
```

Overall i want to take the mean solely on the datetime index but is grouped into MainNames. So this should result in only having 2 indexes. Which is the MainName and DateTime index. Similar to;

```
                               Amount(mm)
                   Date                  
MainName1          1900-01-01         0.0
                   1900-01-02         0.0
                   1900-01-03         5.1
                   1900-01-04         0.0
                   1900-01-05         0.0
                   1900-01-06         0.0
                   1900-01-07         0.0
MainName2          1900-01-04         8.0
                   1900-01-05         9.0
                   1900-01-06         1.0
                   1900-01-07         2.0
```

Comment: What is your code for `concat` ?

Comment: pd.concat(dfs, keys = longsnames) where dfs is the list of dataframes

Comment: what is `print (len(dfs))` ?

Comment: 113....dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample `DataFrames`:

```
print (df1)
print (df2)
print (df3)
            Amount(mm)
Date                  
1900-01-01         0.0
1900-01-02         0.0
1900-01-03         5.1
1900-01-04         0.0
1900-01-05         0.0
1900-01-06         0.0
1900-01-07         0.0
            Amount(mm)
Date                  
1900-01-01         4.0
1900-01-02         5.0
1900-01-03         5.1
1900-01-04         6.0
            Amount(mm)
Date                  
1900-01-04         8.0
1900-01-05         9.0
1900-01-06         1.0
1900-01-07         2.0
```

First is necessary same length of list `longsnames` with number of `DataFrames` (here 3)

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
longsnames = ['MainName1,SubName1', 'MainName1,SubName2', 'MainName2,SubName1']

allvars = pd.concat(dfs, keys = longsnames)
print (allvars)
                               Amount(mm)
                   Date                  
MainName1,SubName1 1900-01-01         0.0
                   1900-01-02         0.0
                   1900-01-03         5.1
                   1900-01-04         0.0
                   1900-01-05         0.0
                   1900-01-06         0.0
                   1900-01-07         0.0
MainName1,SubName2 1900-01-01         4.0
                   1900-01-02         5.0
                   1900-01-03         5.1
                   1900-01-04         6.0
MainName2,SubName1 1900-01-04         8.0
                   1900-01-05         9.0
                   1900-01-06         1.0
                   1900-01-07         2.0
```

then is necessary select first level of `MultiIndex` by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
ShortNames = ['MainName1','MainName2']

idx = allvars.index.get_level_values(0).str.extract('('+ '|'.join(ShortNames) + ')', expand=False)
print (idx)
Index(['MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1',
       'MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1', 'MainName1',
       'MainName1', 'MainName2', 'MainName2', 'MainName2', 'MainName2'],
      dtype='object')
```

And last aggregate `mean`:

```
Allmean = allvars.groupby([idx, 'Date']).mean()
#oldier pandas version alternative
#Allmean = allvars.groupby([idx, allvars.index.get_level_values(1)]).mean()
print (Allmean)
                      Amount(mm)
          Date                  
MainName1 1900-01-01         0.0
          1900-01-02         0.0
          1900-01-03         5.1
          1900-01-04         0.0
          1900-01-05         0.0
          1900-01-06         0.0
          1900-01-07         0.0
MainName2 1900-01-01         4.0
          1900-01-02         5.0
          1900-01-03         5.1
          1900-01-04         6.0
```

Comment: Wasn't the result i was looking for, but thank you for taking the time. I was hoping to just take the mean of the for each day of each MainName. So the result should have still have the date time index, as well as the MainName index. But to fix this would we just change the ```get_level_values(0)``` term to ```get_level_values(1)```?.I will update my post to see what results should be. Also side topic; the length of my longnames and dataframes are the same, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Your responses are so fast! I really appreciate it! I redid your code and it seems that my data might be at fault which was why it was giving me an error, but ill accept your answer now! Thank You again!